# How to check cookie from other website in php and do not allow to access mywebsite?

Tags: php, cookies

How to check cookie from other website in php and do not allow to access mywebsite?

if client is have cookie example

if have cookie from www.example.com it would be redirect to other website?

please help me some people from other website is comment me about bad website and i want check

if have cookie from that i dont want show anything

1. How to disallow to access my website if someone have cookie from exam.com website?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disallow to access my website if someone have cookie from exam.com website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912841/how-to-disallow-to-access-my-website-if-someone-have-cookie-from-exam-com-websit)

Answer (score 5):

It's impossible to view cookies that were set by another website.

Comment: You can try looking at `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Comment: No, a cookie can only be read by the same domain that set it.

Comment: how to disallow if someone have cookie from exam.com website?

Comment: With javascript: `if (confirm("Do you have a cookie from exam.com?")) location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com';`