# How to disallow to access my website if someone have cookie from exam.com website?

Tags: php, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check cookie from other website in php and do not allow to access mywebsite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911389/how-to-check-cookie-from-other-website-in-php-and-do-not-allow-to-access-mywebsit)

How to disallow to access my website if someone have cookie from exam.com website?

i tried for about this in php . please help me thank

Comment: i think the only logical way is with javascript. First use javascript to read all the cookie for all domain (i'm still not sure if it's can. i will check if there way how to do this). then check if there is the cookie of the domain you mean. and if "true", do your function()

Comment: @Mark Baker: yes, it's really a duplicate for me (same case)...

Comment: I'm not sure if you can read cookie files via javascript... I'd hope not, else it's time to disable it again and forget about visit sites that use Ajax. You can read the browser history, which might identify visits to exam.com. Personally, the idea of forbidding access to people who have visited another specific site fills me with foreboding.

Comment: good idea and thank for protect my website from again http://www.stevenyork.com/demos/browser-history-sniffer/download.zip for reading history

Comment: work fine with firefox and ie but it not working for chrome

Answer (score 9):

The answer is simple : you can't because you can't read cookies from other domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the referring URL though. To see if they came directly from exam.com.
`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`